# How to optimize bridge links for structure use?

Tags: death-stranding

Is there a systematic way to choose what other players to enter into bridge contracts with for optimal structure availability / use? More specifically, if I choose to create a link with a high-level player but they haven't logged into the game in several days / weeks, will the link serve no purpose due to structure deterioration?